# SQL Joining table row data

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have this query:

```
SELECT Stops_edited_small1.AtcoCode, ABC.Naptan_Atco, ABC.Stop_Code
FROM Stops_edited_small1
INNER JOIN ABC
ON Stops_edited_small1.AtcoCode=ABC.Naptan_Atco
```

Which returns a nice results table, but what I actually want to do, is, if:

```
Stops_edited_small1.AtcoCode=ABC.Naptan_Atco
```

I want to put that data from ABC.Stop_Code into Stops_edited_small1.ABCStop_Code (which has currently got no values).

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to update `ABC.StopCode` with the value of `Stops_edited_small1.ABCStop_Code`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE     Stops_edited_small1
SET        Stops_edited_small1.ABCStop_Code = ABC.StopCode
FROM       Stops_edited_small1
INNER JOIN ABC ON Stops_edited_small1.AtcoCode = ABC.Naptan_Atco
```

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect! Not used the SET function before :-)